# Are words with the combinations of ia io and ea eo pronounced the same as iya iyo and eya eyo

Tags: pronunciation

I see some words ending with eo or io and I try to pronounce as eyo or iyo but I do not know if that is correct.

Comment: 'Ia' and 'iya' I sometimes find a little hard to distinguish aurally, but I have no trouble at all hearing or pronouncing the difference between eo and eyo.

Comment: eo & io directly blend the sounds of e & o and i & o rather than including a consonantal Y sound as in the word kyou, or in the word yes prefacing the o sound